# How to assign pointers to a complex 3d array in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I would like to know how to assign two pointers, one to the real part of a complex 3d array and another to the imaginary part of the same array in Fortran.

Let's say I have defined a 3d array as such:

complex*16, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable, target :: vftmp

and I would like to assign a pointer to the real part of vftmp(2,1,1) and a pointer to the imaginary part of vftmp(2,1,1). Could someone help me with a snippet please? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you mean pointer assignment, you can't.  The real part of vftmp is of course `real(vftmp,16)`.  You cannot do, for example, `re => real(vftmp,16)`.  BTW, 16 is a nonstandard kind type parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope something like the following is possible

```
real, pointer :: re
complex, target :: z
re => z % re
! or
real, pointer :: re(:,:,:)
complex, target :: z(2,3,4)
re => z(:,:,:) % re
```

but it seems not (or possible with very new compilers...?) So a workaround approach below:

---

1) If the goal is to get (scalar) pointers for the Re and Im parts of a single element of a complex array, I guess we can use `c_f_pointer` such that

```
module testmod
contains
    subroutine getreim_ptr( z, re, im )
        use iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        complex, target, intent(in) :: z
        real, pointer :: re, im, buf(:)

        call c_f_pointer( c_loc( z ), buf, [ 2 ] )

        re => buf( 1 )
        im => buf( 2 )
    end subroutine
end module

program main
    use testmod
    implicit none
    complex :: z( 2, 3 )
    real, pointer :: re, im

    !! Test array.
    z = 0.0
    z( 1, 1 ) = ( 1.0, -1.0 )

    !! Get pointers for the Re/Im parts of z(1,1).
    call getreim_ptr( z( 1, 1 ), re, im )

    print *, "z(1,:) = ", z(1,:)
    print *, "z(2,:) = ", z(2,:)
    print *, "re = ", re
    print *, "im = ", im
end
```

Result (gfortran-8.2):

```
 z(1,:) =   (1.00000000,-1.00000000)  (0.00000000,0.00000000)  (0.00000000,0.00000000)
 z(2,:) =   (0.00000000,0.00000000)   (0.00000000,0.00000000)  (0.00000000,0.00000000)
 re =    1.00000000    
 im =   -1.00000000
```

---

2) If the goal is to get array pointers for the entire complex array, I guess we can use rank-remapping pointer assignments (to point to non-contiguous memory with constant gaps). For example, in the 2D case (for simplicity),

```
re( 1:n1, 1:n2 ) => buf( 1::2 )
im( 1:n1, 1:n2 ) => buf( 2::2 )
```

where `re` and `im` are 2D array pointers and `buf` is a real 1D array pointer that points to an allocatable 2D complex array (via `c_f_pointer`). A minimum example may look like this:

```
module testmod
contains
    subroutine getreim_ptr2d( zarr, re, im )
        use iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        complex, allocatable, target, intent(in) :: zarr(:,:)
        real, pointer :: re(:,:), im(:,:), buf(:)
        integer :: n1, n2

        n1 = size( zarr, 1 )
        n2 = size( zarr, 2 )
        call c_f_pointer( c_loc( zarr ), buf, [ size(zarr) * 2 ] )

        re( 1:n1, 1:n2 ) => buf( 1::2 )
        im( 1:n1, 1:n2 ) => buf( 2::2 )
    end subroutine
end module

program main
    use testmod
    implicit none
    complex, allocatable :: zarr(:,:)
    real, pointer :: re(:,:), im(:,:)
    integer i

    !! Prepare a test array (zarr).
    allocate( zarr( 2, 3 ) )
    zarr(1,:) = [( complex( 100 + i, -100 -i ), i=1,3 )]
    zarr(2,:) = [( complex( 200 + i, -200 -i ), i=1,3 )]
    print *, "shape( zarr ) = ", shape( zarr )
    print *, "zarr(1,:) = ", zarr(1,:)
    print *, "zarr(2,:) = ", zarr(2,:)

    call getreim_ptr2d( zarr, re, im )

    print *
    print *, "shape( re ) = ", shape( re )
    print *, "re(1,:) = ", re(1,:)
    print *, "re(2,:) = ", re(2,:)
    print *
    print *, "shape( im ) = ", shape( im )
    print *, "im(1,:) = ", im(1,:)
    print *, "im(2,:) = ", im(2,:)
end program
```

Result (gfortran 8.2):

```
 shape( zarr ) =            2           3
 zarr(1,:) =  (101.000000,-101.000000)  (102.000000,-102.000000)  (103.000000,-103.000000)
 zarr(2,:) =  (201.000000,-201.000000)  (202.000000,-202.000000)  (203.000000,-203.000000)

 shape( re ) =            2           3
 re(1,:) =    101.000000    102.000000    103.000000    
 re(2,:) =    201.000000    202.000000    203.000000    

 shape( im ) =            2           3
 im(1,:) =   -101.000000   -102.000000   -103.000000    
 im(2,:) =   -201.000000   -202.000000   -203.000000
```

---

Below are some materials we can find on the net:

> The New Features of Fortran 2003 [(N1597)](https://wg5-fortran.org/N1551-N1600/N1579.pdf): 3.7 "Pointer assignment"

"...Remapping of the elements of a rank-one array is permitted:

```
p(1:m,1:2*m) => a(1:2*m*m)
```

The mapping is in array-element order and the target array must be large enough. The bounds may be any scalar integer expressions. The limitation to rank-one arrays is because pointer arrays need not occupy contiguous storage:

```
a => b(1:10:2)
```

but all the gaps have the same length in the rank-one case."

> Fortran 2003 extensions: 5.4.3 Rank-remapping Pointer Assignment [(this page)](http://geco.mines.edu/software/nagfor/nag_f2003.html#AUTOTOC_5_4_3)

"...This feature allows a multi-dimensional pointer to point to a single-dimensional object. For example:

```
REAL,POINTER :: diagonal(:),matrix(:,:),base(:)
...
ALLOCATE(base(n*n))
matrix(1:n,1:n) => base
diagonal => base(::n+1)
!
! DIAGONAL now points to the diagonal elements of MATRIX.
!
```

Note that when rank-remapping, the values for both the lower and upper bounds must be explicitly specified for all dimensions, there are no defaults."

Comment: I don't understand the notations buf(1::2) and buf(2::2) in your code. The value 2 after the colon, is it the stride? Could you explain please? Thanks.

Comment: It is the same as writing buf( 1 : 2*n1*n2 : 2 ) and buf( 2 : 2*n1*n2 : 2 ). We can omit any of a, b, inc in the notation a:b:inc, then they are assumed automatically to be the lower bound (for a), upper bound (for b), and 1 (for inc). (For example, if A is declared as A( 6 ), then A( 1::2 ) (= A( 1:6:2 )) means A(1), A(3), A(5), and A( 2::2 ) (= A( 2:6:2 )) means A(2), A(4), A(6).)

Comment: Just a late addition... The above method creates an array pointer for **non-contiguous** memory, which I think should not be passed to a subroutine that expects an array of contiguous memory (e.g. legacy library routines with explicit-shape or assumed-size dummy arguments). So please be careful...